# About faiss's c_api, can indexpq support uint8 data?

Tags: types, faiss

How to use faiss's c_api for sift1b dataset? I have setup the env successfully. I read the source code of indexpq.h and found that the function "index" only supports float type data, while the data type of the sift1b dataset is uint8. Do I need to convert each data type to float one by one? Or does faiss support uint8 type data?

Here is the related src code in indepq.h:
void train(idx_t n, const float* x) override;
void search(
idx_t n,
const float* x,
idx_t k,
float* distances,
idx_t* labels,
const SearchParameters* params = nullptr) const override;